# Drop service hangs indefinitely

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I have a mirrored database that was using a service broker to push notifications to a client.  The broker creation framework started making duplicates and this caused serious problems so i rolled back to a different framework.

The problem is i cannot cleanup the the existing services that are not longer in use (or should be).

[image]

This line hangs indefinitely.

`DROP SERVICE [dbo_TrackSessionsQueue_3a1daa40-ec44-4425-a81d-4ae5ecf90271]`

- I've tried stopping the broker but i cannot because it is a mirrored database.
- I've tried killing every single transaction in the database to free the lock but that didn't work.
- I've tried working my way up by disabling the queue and then deleting the contracts and message types but i cannot while the service still exists.
- I was able to disable the queues and delete the activation stored procedures but this didn't seem to do anything.
- Most of the queues do appear to have some rows in them.
- `SELECT * FROM sys.transmission_queue` hangs indefinitely as well.
- EDIT: i was able to empty the queue with the following, but it didn't actually fix the issue.

  DECLARE @dialog UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

  ```
  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from <QUEUE>)
  BEGIN 
      WAITFOR( RECEIVE TOP (1)
          @dialog = conversation_handle
          FROM <QUEUE>
      ), TIMEOUT 500 

      end conversation @dialog with cleanup
  end
  ```

I'm afraid i'm going to have to break mirroring in order to make a new broker. This is a live production system and i'd rather not do that..  Anything else i can try?

**BIG EDIT**

So i was able to finally figure out a way to delete ***most*** of them.

I first issued this to empty out the queue

```
-- Create variables used to hold information
DECLARE @dialog UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from [dbo_TrackSessionsQueue_3a1daa40-ec44-4425-a81d-4ae5ecf90271])
BEGIN 
    WAITFOR( RECEIVE TOP (1)
        @dialog = conversation_handle
        FROM dbo. [dbo_TrackSessionsQueue_3a1daa40-ec44-4425-a81d-4ae5ecf90271]
    ), TIMEOUT 500 

    end conversation @dialog with cleanup
end
```

Then i altered the queue with `ACTIVATION ( DROP )`

```
ALTER QUEUE [dbo]. [dbo_TrackSessionsQueue_3a1daa40-ec44-4425-a81d-4ae5ecf90271] WITH STATUS = ON , RETENTION = OFF , ACTIVATION (  DROP  ), POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING (STATUS = OFF)
```

After this i was able to drop the service and then the queue. It only seems to take 3-4 minutes per queue to delete.

```
DROP service [dbo_TrackSessionsQueue_3a1daa40-ec44-4425-a81d-4ae5ecf90271]
DROP QUEUE [dbo_TrackSessionsQueue_3a1daa40-ec44-4425-a81d-4ae5ecf90271]
```

At this point all but 2 of the 15 services that refused to drop to have been deleted after stopping and retrying over and over again.

**There obviously is something blocking here but as discussed in the comments there isn't anything blocking when i run `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests`**

Comment: Who is the drop being blocked by? You should be able to tell in sys.dm_exec_requests

Comment: I'll assume its the `DROP SERVICE` task. It appears to have a wait_type of null and a last wait type of `PAGELATCH_EX`...  so, its not?

Comment: What is the blocking_session_id for that row? THAT is the task you need to check on.

Comment: There isn't one. I feel there's some microsoft voodo going on here. I found a route for deleting most of them. I'll post that in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately i had to go the route i didn't want to. I had to break mirroring for the database and then create a new broker using:

`ALTER DATABASE <db> SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`

Once this completed i was able to instantly delete the services that were stuck.

My attempts to drop the services without setting the new broker actually completely broke my mirroring anyways so i was kinda forced into this method.